Google Sheets match() function
I want to match the data in cells C2, C3 etc. in column A and retrieve the value from the next 8 rows. I'll attach the Google Sheet where you can see my example.
I tried several times with the matching formula, but with no results, so here I am :P
Pic example
sheet
Match formula, xlookup, vlookup


You may try this in Cell_D2:
=map(C2:C131,lambda(Σ,ifna(torow(offset(A1,xmatch(Σ,A:A),,8)))))



Thanks you @rockinfreakshow it works :DD follow for you!!
